# Internet Explorer 7.0 CSS Hack

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm in need of inserting a Hack to a web page, so it works well on IE7.0
But I'm having issues with the way I'm doing things. It should be simple.

The actual CSS code is the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { margin:0;}
#home_splash { background-image:url(homeimages/image-background.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-x; background-position:left top;}
#home_splash #home_text { height:470px; padding-top:25px;padding-left:38px; }
#home_splash #home_text_1,
#home_splash #home_text_2 { display:none; }
#home_splash #home_text_1 { width:172px; height:58px; top:0px; left:70px; position:relative; background:inherit; background-position: -70px 0px; }
#home_splash #home_text_2 { width:212px; height:27px; top:460px; left:868px; position:relative; background:inherit; background-position: -868px -460px; }
#home_splash {background-color:#d1d1d9;margin-top:-15px; background-repeat:repeat;width:100%; }
#home_splash .picture { background-image: url(homeimage/image.jpg); width:960px; height:520px; display:block; margin-top:20px; margin-left :auto; margin-right:auto; }
#home_splash #boxes { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;padding-top:0px; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; height:190px; width:930px;}
#home_splash #boxes .box { width:33%; float:left; display:block;background-repeat:repeat-x;}
#home_splash #boxes h3 { font-size:23px; border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcc4; color:#000033; margin:0; }
#home_splash #boxes h3,
#home_splash #boxes p {margin: 4px 25px; }
#home_splash #boxes p { line-height:160%; }
#home_splash #boxes .box_separator { border-right:1px solid #eee;}
ul#nav { width:100%; height:37px; margin:0px;display:block; background-color:#000; background-repeat:repeat-x; }
#container {background-color:#d1d1d9; zoom:1; }
#content { margin:0; } 
.splash_text {width:885px; height:463px;}
</style>
```

I'd like to make ONE CHANGE in this CSS.

I'd like change the following line :

```
#home_splash .picture { background-image: url(homeimage/image.jpg); width:960px; height:520px; display:block; margin-top:20px; margin-left :auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

**I want IE7.0 to remove the 'margin-top:20px;' property - but INLINE in this html file only**

Comment: If there is a CSS inconsistency, can you recreate it on jsfiddle? There are sometimes ways to circumvent without catering browser-specific styles.

Comment: s/sometimes/usually/.  Unfortunately jsFiddle doesn't support IE <9 IIRC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conditional comments are exactly what you need. I'm assuming by "rmeove the margin-top: 20px' property, you mean set it to 0 (as there's really no other way to remove it). Here's the code:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><style type="text/css">#home_splash .picture { margin-top: 0; }</style<![endif]-->
```

Just stick that in your HTML file, below the CSS you already have, and you should be golden.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're coding into an HTML file, by far the easiest option is conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE 7 here
<![endif]-->
```

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the hack in the same css as the other browsers:

```
    *+ html #home_splash .picture { background-image: url(homeimage/image.jpg);}
```

Look here:
http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Star_Html_Hack